# How to share code between multiple repositories (React projects)?

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, repository, yarnpkg

A part from turning the projects into a Monorepo, what would the best approach be to share code between multiple repos? These are just a few helper functions that all 3 projects share.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can create your own npm package for common things and then install it in your all projects

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. Is there a way to make this npm package private so that only certain people can use it? It'd contain some private company code

Comment: I know that you can install package from github repository. In this way I suppose you can create a private repository there and then use it